# Copying gemset after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rvm

Hi I am having a ruby website for my client. I dont have much knowledge in ruby. Site was working fine before. I migrated the same setup to a new server. After migration,

```
rvm was unable to use appname@1.9.3
```

So, I check for the gemlists in both the servers.

OLD SERVER

```
root@host [/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers]# rvm gemset list_all

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p484 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484)
=> (default)
   global
   appname
```

NEW SERVER

```
root@host [/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547]# rvm gemset list_all
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p547'.

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p547 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547)
=> (default)
   global
```

Apart from the path error, I noticed, one gemset is missing in the new server. How can I import that to new?

Comment: From your app root folder on new server can you start rails server by 
'rails s' ?

Comment: I think you should not import gemset. You can create gemset on new server `rvm gemset create appname` ([doc](http://rvm.io/gemsets/creating)), start use it (http://rvm.io/gemsets/using) and run `bundle install` from project root. All gems should be installed in the active gemset

Answer (score 0):

create the following files in your project's root directory:

.ruby-gemset:
`appname`

.ruby-version:
`1.9.3`

Then go to your project directory with `cd PROJECT_ROOT`, and run `bundle install`

You can find more information about those files here:
http://rvm.io/workflow/projects